# Upcasting NSObject to RLMObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

How would you upcast an `NSObject` to a `RLMObject`?

Say you have a model object that's of type `NSObject`, and say you wanted to dynamically upcast it to `RLMObject`, how would you do it?

It's worth mentioning that `RLMObject`'s properties can't be populated at runtime, else I probably would've done it through `<objc/runtime.h>`. (I mean.. They technically can... It would just be too much of a hack)

**What I'm trying to do:**

The main purpose behind this is to create a caching framework that would dynamically choose between interchangeable caching dependencies such as Realm, SQLite, Core Data, etc. For example, I imagine having a preprocessor flag to hopefully switch from using Realm to SQLite, without having to change my models subclass.

This would require all of my models being a subclass of `NSObject`, simply because `RLMObject` wouldn't make sense in a SQLite environment for example.

I've been thinking about this a whole lot, and here's my approach:

1) Loop through the `NSObject`'s properties at runtime & create a key/value object of them

2) Create a subclass of `RLMObject` at runtime and copy the property list from the passed `NSObject` model

3) Utilize Realm's `initWithValue:` to populate the properties

What's your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this method that you mention - `RLMObject.initWithValue` or a static equivalent [`createInDefaultRealmWithValue`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMObject(cm)createInDefaultRealmWithValue:) has to be called on an RLMObject subclass, or else it throws an exception: "Object type 'RLMObject' is not managed by the Realm".

You need a dynamic schema creation API (what underlies RLMObject), that I don't see being a public API.

An alternative would be to manually encode the object to some dictionary or NSData and attach it to a fixed RLMObject subclass.

You might lose some Realm features by not inheriting RLMObject like knowing when the object becomes dirty, but still probably get some success.

I think you'll get the same problem with Core Data. Normally Core Data supports only `NSManagedObject` subclasses, and moreover it requires you to define a fixed schema in advance in a model file (represented in code by `NSManagedObjectModel`).

Of course you could just treat your objects as dictionaries of property names and values, and place them into a giant ("type","id","property","value") table, but it is not the best approach (likely to be slow).

The same strategy is possible to implement with the SQLite backend. Interesting to see which schema would you choose for this.

I'd recommend to look at key-value stores as the backend for this, and avoid SQL. Or treat SQL as a key-value store, as in ("type+id", "encoded_object_data") :)

Comment: In my opinion, there would still be a need to either upcast or dynamically create the subclass of `RLMObject` at runtime, no matter how you’d twist it. The main reason of this would be that if you call `initWithValue:` on a class type `RLMObject` (not a subclass), it would always return an empty schema due to the object having 0 properties. Let me know if you have any thoughts to this or any other ideas :)

Comment: I believe that the schema won't be empty, it will be populated via KVC from your object. To be clear, I mean code like: `RLMObject *cacheObject = [RLMObject createInDefaultRealmWithValue:plainObject];`, where `plainObject` is not a subclass of anything special, but it is KVC-compliant.

Comment: I just checked it out. It throws an exception: `Object type 'RLMObject' is not managed by the Realm`.

Comment: I’m basically just creating model that’s a subclass of NSObject with 2 readwrite properties that I then to pass in to ‘createInDefaultRealmWithValue:’. That throws an exception.

Comment: I see what you mean. Looks like you have to call this method through a subclass, not through RLMObject... Then my idea is wrong. I think it's best if you forward this question to Realm support, because likely you need to go a level deeper than RLMObject to create dynamically schema objects yourself. An alternative would be to manually encode the object to some dictionary or NSData and attach it to a fixed RLMObject subclass.

Comment: I’ll try to contact support. Attaching a dictionary or similar is too much of a hack imo. Thanks for your assistance either way :D I’ll try to keep you posted to what the final decision comes to.